# Warning: "Could not get traitsetID for iPhone11,6" (Assets.xcassets)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this warning all the time when running an Xcode 10 app to the XS Max physical device:

*Could not get traitsetID for iPhone11,6* (Assets.xcassets)

Any idea what this is about and how to fix it?

Comment: Me too w/ a Max device. And yes iPhone11,6 means the max.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this tonight as well, was fixed when I ran the update of my phone to 12.1.   Don't know if that was the fix, or if it was coincidental, but it's working now.

Comment: I get the warning with 12.1. Which device do you use and does the warning contain the same number 11,6?

Comment: i'm using a physical XS Max as well, and yes, the build error in DEBUG was exactly the same (Could not get traitsetID for iPhone 11,6)  Was weird though in that it worked in RELEASE mode.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it was something with the recent XCode update + iPhone XR/XS/XS Max + iOS 12.1 update all being released at the same time. Race condition! :)